# Python multiprocessing freeze

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run this code, but it returns an error. I didn't understandig that. What could cause this to occur and how should I fix/troubleshoot the problem?

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy

dados = pd.read_csv('treino.csv')

nlp = spacy.load('pt_core_news_sm')

textos_para_tratamento = (titulos.lower() for titulos in dados['title'])

def trata_textos(doc):
   tokens_validos = []
   for token in doc:
      e_valido = not token.is_stop and token.is_alpha
      if e_valido:
         tokens_validos.append(token.text)
      if len(tokens_validos) > 2:
         return ' '.join(tokens_validos)

textos_tratados = [trata_textos(doc) for doc in nlp.pipe(textos_para_tratamento,
                                                    batch_size= 1000,
                                                    n_process = -1)]
```

The error message:

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
child process and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
in the main module:

```
  if__name__=='__main__':
     freeze_support()
        ...
```

The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: It would appear `spacy` utilizes multiprocessing internally, and some calls to the library must only occur in the `__main__` file, and not when the file is imported. This is important due to how multiprocessing works. using the `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause will prevent code execution on import. `freeze_support()` is only needed if you plan on converting your script to a windows exe using something like pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you to reorganize your code to only run once in the main module.  Since your code isn't runnable as given, I can only suggest the following reorganization:

```py
import pandas as pd
import spacy

def trata_textos(doc):
   tokens_validos = []
   for token in doc:
      e_valido = not token.is_stop and token.is_alpha
      if e_valido:
         tokens_validos.append(token.text)
      if len(tokens_validos) > 2:
         return ' '.join(tokens_validos)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dados = pd.read_csv('treino.csv')
    nlp = spacy.load('pt_core_news_sm')
    textos_para_tratamento = (titulos.lower() for titulos in dados['title'])
    textos_tratados = [trata_textos(doc) for doc in nlp.pipe(textos_para_tratamento,
                                                             batch_size= 1000,
                                                             n_process = -1)]
```